# JSP doesnt see my java class?

Tags: java, jsp, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to create objects of my own java class in jsp .See below

Directory Structure

[image]

jsptest is my project name

**index.jsp**

```
<%@page import="java.util.Date"%>

<body>
    Hi Today is 
    <%out.println(new Date());%>
    <% Test t;%>
</body>
```

**Test.java**

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}
```

Without the line `<% Test t;%>` it works and prints

```
 Hi Today is Thu Jan 07 14:30:00 IST 2016
```

When I add it however this is what I get

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 7 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
Test cannot be resolved to a type
4: <body>
5:  Hi Today is 
6:  <%out.println(new Date());%>
7:  <% Test t;%>
8: </body>
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:198)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:450)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:361)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:585)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: You need to import to use it

Comment: addes this `<%@page import="Test"%>` , no luck

Comment: did you restart tomcat / redeploy your app after compiling class into WEB-INF/classes ?

Comment: I did ,I tried many times

Comment: Yes I did many times

Comment: Move your Test class to package and import package in jsp, classes without package won't be identified by jsp page in tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you should put your class in a package : like  `foo.bar.Test`
After import your class in the JSP file : `<%@page import="foo.bar.Test"%>`

then as mentioned in your code you are using a main methode in your Test calss ( used in desktop apps ) it is not called in The JSP file : 
so , you have to create a static Methode in the Test class then call it from JSP .

**index.jsp**

```
<%@page import="java.util.Date"%>
<%@page import="foo.bar.Test"%>

<body>
    Hi Today is 
    <%out.println(new Date());%>
    <% Test.myMethode();%>
</body>
```

**Test.java**

```
package foo.bar;


public class Test{

    public static void myMethode() {
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the `Test.java` file should be in the `Classes` folder. It should be placed on `src` folder. Use a `package`.

You didn't imported the `Test` class of yours. You must import it.Add the following line.

```
<%@page import="your.package.name.Test"%> //Replace with your package name
```

**P.S.:** It is better to use a library instead of using just JSP.Try to learn about them too.

[Find out about JSTL](https://jstl.java.net/)

Comment: I did see my comments

Comment: You should add the full path to your Test class <%@page import="xxx.yyy.Test"%>

Comment: Where is your `Test.java` file is in ? It should be in the `src` folder.

Comment: @dsp_user Yes. He must. But as his folder structure shows, he do not have any packages. Just the class.

Comment: Its not necessary to keep `java` files in `src` folder. @ThisaruGuruge

Comment: If you're using a default package (and so it seems), this might be a problem.

Comment: @SainathS.R place your `java` class in a package otherthan default package as you did..

Comment: And I don't think you can call your Test.main() from a jsp file. I haven't tried this, but I don't expect it to work. Normally, your jsp should be use with a servlet , not a console application.

Comment: I said it __Should__ it's not a good practice to place them outside `src`  folder. Using packages is also the same. You should use packages. and then import the class properly. anyway, I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use tomcat as your servlet container ,your index.jsp will be translate to a servlet named like index_jsp.java and compile to a class file named like index_jsp.class , which located in the directory of $TOMCAT_HOME/work/Catalina/localhost/_/org/apache/jsp .

They two class file  are not in the same package (directory),so you should import Test like

```
<%@page import="java.util.Date，Test"%>
```

Use a comma as delimiter, or write two page directives like

```
<%@page import="java.util.Date"%>
<%@page import="Test"%>
```

P.S.: Why Test.java in the directory of WEB-INF/classes ?